Actual CSS of a tailwind class in VSCode is only shown on hover, not while typing in intellisense
VSCode tailwind extension shows the actual CSS styles of a tailwind class only when the tailwind class is hovered, not while typing the tailwind class. How to see the actual CSS of a tailwind class in intellisense while coding?
Showing this in left panel
Instead of this
I tried hitting ctrl space on the intellisense suggestions. I have used jetbrains product like webstorm, which shows the CSS implementation of each tailwind intellisense suggestion when we press ctrl q (in vscode, it is usually done by ctrl space).

You may want to identify what VSCode extension is being used for this and file a BUG in their system (e.g. Github). These details you'll find in the details of the Extension. You will want to specify the exact Tailwind extension (e.g. Tailwind CSS IntelliSense, v0.10.5) and the version, that you're using. We presume you're using VScode with Microsoft's marketplace and not the Open Source VSCode ...
